# How to sort a nested array in JavaScript in ascending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a nested array like this `var input = [2, 4, 2, 6, 1, [4, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1, 6, [2, 1], [1]], [1], 5];` and the output should be sorted in such a way that, all the numbers should come first in its ascending order and if the array contains subarrays it should come in the order of its length. That is, subarray with length 1 should come first, subarray with length 2 come second etc. Also if there are numbers in it, it should be sorted ascending.

`var output = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, [1], [1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 6, [1], [1, 2]]];`

Below is my implementation but it sorts only one level deep. How to call it recursively?

```
function sortArray(arr) {
  return [...arr]
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) return a.length - b.length;
      else if (Array.isArray(a) || Array.isArray(b)) return 1;
      else return a - b;
    });
}
```

Comment: There's a mistake in your comparison function where it does `return 1` even if `Array.isArray(b)` - it should  `return -1` then.

Comment: @Bergi, when a is an array and b, is number or vice versa, the array should come last.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When `a` is a number and `b` is an array, the number should come first - so you need to return a negative value.

Comment: @Bergi got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` on the array before you sort it, and if the item is an array call `sortArr`:

```js
function sortArray(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(a => Array.isArray(a) ? sortArray(a) : a)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) return a.length - b.length;
      else if (Array.isArray(a)) return 1;
      else if (Array.isArray(b)) return -1;
      else return a - b;
    });
}

const input = [2, 4, 2, 6, 1, [4, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1, 6, [2, 1], [1]], [1], 5];

const result = sortArray(input);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by creating recursive function using `forEach` loop and also using `sort` method.

```js
var input = [2, 4, 2, 6, 1, [4, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1, 6, [2, 1], [1]], [1], 5];

function deepSort(data) {
  data.sort((a, b) => !Array.isArray(b) - !Array.isArray(a) || a - b || a.length - b.length)
  data.forEach(e => Array.isArray(e) && deepSort(e))
}


deepSort(input);
console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```